# Prove the infimum is a minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

They give me $S^{n-1}$ = { $x \in \mathbb{R^n} : \left \| x \right \|_2=1$  } the unit sphere and the hyperplane $H$ define as $H = ${ $x \in \mathbb{R^n} : <x,a> = c $ } with $a \in S^{n-1}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $c \geq 1$.

1. Prove that the infimum of the distance between $S^{n-1}$ and $H$ is a minimum.

   $d(S^{n-1},H) = $ inf { $ \left \| x - y \right \|_2 : x \in S^{n-1}, y \in H$ }

Comment: Can you visualize the situation? If $c=1$ then clearly the distance is zero, achieved at $x=a$. What do you think the distance will be if $c>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^{n-1}$ is a compact set and $H$ is a  closed set. For any compact set $K$ and closed set $C$ the distance $d(K,C)$ is attained.

**Proof:** there exist a sequence $x_n \in K, y_n \in C$ such that $\|x_n-y_n\| \to d(K,C)$. There is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which converges to some point $x \in K$. Now $\|x_n-y_n\|<1+d(K,C)$ for $n$ sufficiently large and $\|x_{n_k}\|$ is bounded so $\|y_{n_k}\|$ is also bounded. So it has  a convergent subsequence converging to some point $y$ of $C$.

Can you now show that $d(x,y)=d(K,C)$?

Comment: @Alvaro $\|x-y\| \leq \|x-x_{n_k}\|+\|x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}\|+\|y-y_{n_k}\| \to 0+d(K,C)+0$ (along the sub subsequence you have chosen).

Comment: I'm trying but I can't, the thing I'm doing is:

Assuming that $d(x,x_n) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $d(y,y_n) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and then trying $d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_n) + d(x_n,y_n) + d(y_n,y) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + d(S^{n-1},H) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = d(S^{n-1},H) + \epsilon$ and making $\epsilon \to 0$ I reach $d(x,y) \leq d(S^{n-1},H)$ 

I delete the previous comment because I was editing it, sorry.

Comment: Well but for the other side of the inequality I don't know what to do, I don't know how to show the $d(S^{n-1},H) \leq d(x,y)$

Comment: @Alvaro $d(K,C) =\lim \|x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}\|$ and $\|x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}\| \leq \|x_{n_k}-x\|+\|x-y\|+\|y_{n_k}-y\|$

Comment: Okay, I understand it right now